# What caused this reaction between chlorine and brake fluid?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

I recently saw a video on Facebook of a couple of people pouring brake fluid into a bottle containing pool chemicals (chlorine pellets, I believe). Now this was a rather strong exothermic reaction, resulting in a fire. At one point during the fire, fire appeared to be vapors burning under pressure (like a propane tank fire). I have included a link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPExgRcpEYI). Unfortunately, it is not the original video that I watched.

My question here is what in the brake fluid is reacting so strongly with the chlorine? And what are the chemical products of this reaction (what's in the smoke)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pool Chlorine is calcium hypochlorite and brake fluid is polyethylene glycol. [Here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiqxMT3w7PSAhUKj1QKHUwiCUMQFghFMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencemadness.org%2Ftalk%2Ffiles.php%3Fpid%3D75149%26aid%3D1734&usg=AFQjCNGKOJX5eNJTR8MPy-uLtq8oa6B4og&sig2=th1e0vSLHSy0ZD_QjIf2YQ&bvm=bv.148073327,d.cGw) is a proposed mechanism for the reaction.

Comment: Thank you for your response! If no one else responds, I will likely accept this answer. :)

Comment: This reference looks like a good find. Writing out at least the key parts of the reaction would _greatly_ increase the quality of your answer, and probably earn you more up-votes ;)